# Bitmex sample-market-maker [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]

Tags: python, bitmex

I setup Bitmex sample-market-maker using python and after running marketmaker XBTUSD I get this output:

```
2020-05-14 00:29:58,439 - INFO - market_maker - BitMEX Market Maker Version: v1.1

2020-05-14 00:29:58,439 - INFO - ws_thread - Connecting to wss://testnet.bitmex.com/realtime?subscribe=quote:XBTUSD,trade:XBTUSD,instrument,order:XBTUSD,execution:XBTUSD,margin,position
2020-05-14 00:29:58,439 - INFO - ws_thread - Authenticating with API Key.
2020-05-14 00:29:58,440 - INFO - ws_thread - Started thread
2020-05-14 00:29:58,733 - ERROR - ws_thread - [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)
2020-05-14 00:29:58,734 - INFO - ws_thread - Websocket Closed
2020-05-14 00:29:59,445 - ERROR - ws_thread - Couldn't connect to WS! Exiting.
```

I don't need to update my OS, python, or pip, and the site certificate is valid. Please help!

Comment: Based on the fact that `Authenticating with API Key` comes before `CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED` I would guess that it is not the main certificate for `testnet.bitmex.com` that is failing. Can you increase the log level to DEBUG?

Comment: @lxop I increased to DEBUG and got the same output, but some of the "INFO" said "DEBUG" instead

Comment: I've just tried setting it up myself, and it worked without any certificate issues. I wonder if your OS certificate CA store doesn't have the Amazon CA that bitmex is issued from. Are you on linux or OSX? If so what happens when you run `curl -v https://testnet.bitmex.com`?